# Link not working (but displaying as followable) img is the selector, shown in a list, with an on hover effect

Tags: html, css, image, hyperlink, hover

As the title states I'm having a bit of trouble with an element on my 'work in progress' website.

I currently have an unordered list which provides square sections (with a different image and link in each) On a hover, the image changes opacity and the background color changes also.

The problem I'm facing is that while the cosmetic effects are all working fine, the link is not working on click. (However, the link does display in the bottom of my browser as 'followable' and right clicking allows for following the link through the options there.

The link for the element is http://www.techcom.co.nz/#myclients

and currently the only element with an attached link is the img for steam. (Column 2, Row 2)

Any help anyone can offer would be greatly appreciated.

Regards

Comment: Please post some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following code to your images...use javascript

```
  example
  <img src="" alt="" onclick='window.location="URL HERE"'>
```

please remember not to get the quote marks mixed because it will not work otherwise and looking at your source you have no URL the images should be going to apart from #

[image]

Comment: Spot on, cheers for that. That works great. Is there a reasoning why my a tag links were not working? And secondly, is there a way for the javascripted link to open in the new tab? Regards

Edited: Currently this is all in testing stage so the only linked image is the steam one. None of the others have been assigned a link yet. (Getting one working before assigning the fix to all the others)

Comment: yes the javascript can open in a new tab and this happens sometimes when your you use styling because they can cancel eachother

Comment: try `onClick="window.open('url','_blank')"`

Comment: @pa5quinade try this "URL HERE","_blank"

Comment: @pa5quinade I understand why you only put a URL on one image.(for testing purposes) and if my answer is good please state it is as answer

Comment: Thanks everyone for your assistance, have it sorted now so I can go ahead with the others, I shall endeavor to fix the a tags but that is not a priority at this point in time. Anyone else that had this problem the fix was IP ADDRESS's for the links and Batu Zet's for the new tab. Thanks everyone.

Comment: @pa5quinade can you please push the arrow to mark the answer as useful so the answer appears nearer to the top of the page. Thanks.

Comment: @pa5quinade you should vote answers up which have helped you so other people when looking at your question can find the best answer fast hence one with the most votes.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand exactly what's the problem.
The links on "my work" section are not working because the links to "#" (none) try to give them real url.

Comment: Currently as this is the website is in testing stage I only gave a link to the "Steam" Image. The problem lies somewhere there, if it could help I can assign a link to the others.